# How to send HTML form data to a Salesforce Marketing Cloud data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I want to use a custom HTML form on my website footer for email newsletter signup and post that data to a Salesforce Marketing Cloud Data Extension.

What's the best way to get that data to Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

The HTML form is pretty straightforward: Email Address, some hidden values including subscriber key (also email address) and date of signup.

Comment: Have you looked at the help docs? I believe you want to use the web collect feature https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_email_studio_web_collect.htm&type=5

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a CloudPage and rather have the form on your own website. You can use DEManager.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5

Comment: That was ridiculously easy and SOLVED my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are looking for is called Smart Capture:

> Smart Capture is a tool in Email Studio you use to create lead capture
>   forms to include in your landing pages. When a lead completes the form
>   on the landing page and clicks the Submit button, the Smart Capture
>   form automatically adds the information to the subscriber list, data
>   extension, or outside data source such as an integrated CRM system.

Here's how-to:

Create a [Smart Capture Form in CloudPages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_create_a_smart_capture_form_in_cloudpages.htm&type=5)

1. Create a sendable Data Extension with all the form fields, including hidden fields
2. In CloudPages, create a new CloudPage and drag the Smart Capture gear to the content area of a landing page
3. Build your form by dragging attributes to the Form Builder content area
4. Click Save and publish the CloudPage

You can later add it to Journey Builder to send a confirmation email.

iFrame it to use it on a landing page outside of Marketing Cloud.